# How to install openstack autopilot without JUJU & MAAS

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I want to install the Openstack in a single node (one server) using the [Ubuntu Autopilot](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html)
, but I don't want install the JUJU and MAAS.

Yes, I try the command in the link above:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install openstack
$ sudo openstack-install
```

The last command returns:

> sudo: openstack-install: command not found

Can I install the Openstack without JUJU and MAAS? I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The packages and dependencies needed for OpenStack are in the Canonical Cloud Archive, which is not the archie you have installed. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive for details. You can use those packages together with puppet or chef or your preferred configuraiton management system to build whatever kind of openstack you like.

However, the recommended approach is to use Juju and MAAS. The juju charms model the various applications in openstack much more naturally and you will find it infinitely easier for build small, medium or large openstack clouds if you master juju. I have seen many substantial teams, who initially rejected Juju because it was different to their existing tools, who came back to it with relief after suffering through a large deployment without it. The reason is that Juju models applications at scale, it doesn't worry so much about machines. That means you focus on the components you want.

I would suggest you start with the conjure-up tool, as a way to start to understand Juju and OpenStack better. Use 16.04 and try apt install openstack, sudo conjure-up openstack.

Comment: I understand. i'm installing the openstack with JUJU now in ubuntu Server 16.04, however my network velocity is 2MB, How long does it take to install? Computer test: HD:500GB RAM:4GB CPU:AMD FX4300

Comment: It might take a while. How many machines are you using? MAAS usually includes a proxy so there i a cache of stuff downloaded before, if you are setting up multiple machines that makes a big difference.

Comment: I'm using one machine with the specification above without MAAS, I've just JUJU

Comment: The OpenStack is installing two days, the only message that appears and doesn't change is "Waiting for Keystone"

Comment: OK, sounds like it is stuck. Are you using the conjure-up tool?

Comment: Yes. But the instalation failed. I'll restart the instalation, but the hardware configuration is much smaller than the [requisites](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html). Can I install and execute the instances? (Or just for initials tests and do a after hardware update)